# How to resolve the build error on react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a build  environment to make an android app but I haven't been able to succeed to build the project. The build log is as follows,

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 5 s 673 ms
:ReactNative:Running '[node, -e, console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\WorkSpace\MyProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 179

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Cannot run program "node" (in directory "C:\WorkSpace\MyProject\android"): CreateProcess error=2, �w�肳�ꂽ�t�@�C����������܂���B
```

It looks exactly same as the link below and I did the same thing but I can't resolve the problem and the log that it makes is always the same.

https://forums.expo.io/t/android-cannot-run-program-node-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory/37693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstall node. delete node modules and
clean and run the project again.

I can't comment so i answered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I still have the same problem...
I'm using nvm to install/uninstall the node, and I reinstall the node (ver 14.6.0) and deleted node modules and clean and run the project.

The node modules that you mentioned was "MyProject\node_modules", right? What I did was basically renamed the folder and tried to clear and rebuild the project again. Please tell me if something is wrong from what you explained, thanks.

Comment: just delete node_modules completely. It will download again. And download latest node using chocolaty(sry for the spelling). Then if u again get error then it might be some other issue we look at it later.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you know how download node_modules again? I delete the folder and install the latest nodejs by using chocolatey but it didn't create node_modules. And I got the message below when I build the react native project again.


Could not read script 'C:\WorkSpace\MyProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I renew nodejs that I was using and it solved it.

> Before:14.6.0

> After:14.7.0

I don't know exactly why and node_modules seems to be not changed at all but at least a build succeeded.

Comment: i'm using older version of node js. I never thought node will cause problem.